# On the construction of the de Rham period ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, local-field, hodge-theory

I'm currently reading "CMI Summer School Notes on $p$-adic Hodge Theory"([https://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/papers/notes.pdf)) p.51 and could not understand why there exists a canonical algebra structure
$$\overline{k} \to \mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}/(p)$$

where $K$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\overline{K}$ is a fixed algebraic closure of $K$, $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}$ is its ring of integers and $\overline{k}$ is its residue field.

Here is my attempt. As $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}/(p)$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/(p)$, it suffices to construct a ring morphism $\overline{k} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}/(p)$. For $x \in \overline{k}$, choose a lift $y_0 \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}$ of $x$ and also choose a sequence $(y_n)$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{K}}$ such that $y_{n+1}^p=y_n$. Then, I thought,
$$x \mapsto \lim y_n^{p^{-n}}$$
is the desired map, is it right? If it is right, I don't see why this yields a well-defined map, i.e., I don't really see why the indeterminacy of the choice of lifts $(y_n)$ is killed by modulo $p$.

Comment: Really have not thought it through, but my first idea would be to imitate the construction of Teichmüller representatives, as follows: Start with $s: \bar k \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\bar K}$ any fixed lift / choice of representatives. $\bar k$ is perfect, so $x^{p^{-n}}$ is well-defined for all $x \in \bar k, n \in \mathbb N$. Then $\tau: x \mapsto \lim_{n\to \infty} (s(x^{p^{-n}}))^{p^n}$ might induce, mod $p$, the map we're after.

Comment: We have a natural map $O_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}}/(p) \rightarrow O_{\overline{K}}/(p)$, and $O_{\mathbb{Q}_p^{nr}}/(p)$ is isomorphic to $\overline{k}$, no?